# How to cut filename from text

Tags: bash

I have file with following line:

```
2014-Aug-26 03:45:31    Operation 1
2014-Aug-26 03:45:32    NEW-1, operation successfully completed: /log/log_1/log_/log_3/log_4/log_5/file_name.xml
2014-Aug-26 03:45:37    Operation 2
```

The name of this file will be always after: `NEW-1, operation successfully completed: /log/log_1/log_/log_3/log_4/log_5/`

I would like to cut from this log only `file_name.xml`. Could someone help?

Comment: Cannot be answered, as we do not have enough information about the log format. Is there always a colon before a filename? Is there always a *filename* after a colon? Or is anything ending with ".xml" a filename? You need something you can "anchor" your filename extraction on.

Comment: Something like `grep 'operation successfully completed' file|grep -o '[^/]\+$'`, but without more information it's hard to tell what the criteria are.

Comment: @Biffen: I'd rather the filename be extracted via `basename` than doing a grep for the last slash.

Comment: The name of this file will be always after: NEW-1, operation successfully completed: /log/log_1/log_/log_3/log_4/log_5/

Comment: @DevSolar Agreed, but the path part will still have to be separated from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed -n 's~.*NEW-1, operation successfully completed: /log/log_1/log_/log_3/log_4/log_5/\(.*\)~\1~p' file
file_name.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
$ grep "NEW-1" | awk -F"/" '{print$NF}'
```

NF means the last field